# Difference in path using ThisWorkbook/ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks in the same folder. Execute macro from one. For this code works properly, but when I change ActiveWorkbook by ThisWorkbook it is not working. Error message with path to some .../Users/myUser/.... is displayed, but this is not a place where files are storaged.

```
book2Name = "workbook.xlsx"
book2NamePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & book2Name
If IsOpen(book2Name) = False Then Workbooks.Open (book2NamePath)
```

Could someone explain it to m?

Comment: I would enable the Immediate Window and try `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path` and `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path` and see what you get. Are you sure this macro is running from one of the two workbooks, or is it in personal.xlsb?

Comment: If you open the workbook directly from an email it will save it in the `Temporary Internet Files` folder which is in `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\...`, or as @J.Fox says - it could be running from the `personal.xlsb` or maybe an `add-in`?

Comment: activeworkbook is the wb which is active at the moment whereas Thisworkbook is the wb in which the code is located

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes you are right, it is downloaded directly from email but saved in folder on desktop. So how can I change this?

Comment: If you're saving it on the desktop before opening it then that's not the problem.  As @ExcelinEfendisi has said - ActiveWorkbook can be different from ThisWorkbook.  When you first open a workbook it becomes the ActiveWorkbook, or when you use `Workbook.Activate`.  `ThisWorkbook` is always the workbook that contains the code you're running.  When you look at the `Project Explorer` in the Visual Basic Editor how many workbooks are open?  (they'll each be heading similar to `VBAProject(PERSONAL.XLSB)`).

Comment: Got it. So instead of putting code into personal I should add module to certain workbook. That should solve problem. Thanks a lot for this explanation!

Comment: Yes, `Personal.xlsb` opens every time you open Excel.  It's useful to store code that can be used on any workbook, or on the application itself (e.g. my work insists that new workbook are in 2003 format due to some legacy bs, so I've added code that changes this to 2010 without me having to manually select it each time I save a workbook).  So, add your code to a normal module in the workbook that the code needs to run in and reference that workbook as `ThisWorkbook`.